# Cоздать HashMap из массивов

Tags: java

Учу Java только третью неделю и в учебных целях пытаюсь сделать программку, которая бы считывала данные о ценах бензинов из таблицы в html и производила бы разные действия со столбиками таблицы - вычисляла среднее, минимум, максимум и т.д.

Набросал такой вот код. С помощью метода `contentToArray` считываю в массив сначала шапку таблицы, а затем данные. Метод `divideTable`, по задумке, делит данные таблицы на столбцы и должен бы столбцы записывать в `HashMap`, где ключ - имя столбца из массива `headers`, а данные - `ArrayList`.

Но заполнять `ArrayList` в `HashMap` поэлементно, я так понял я не могу, поэтому использовал буферный массив, для того чтобы добавлять в карту сразу ключ с заполненным массивом.

Но так как `HashMap` хранит в себе ссылки на массивы, а не данные, при обнулении буфера обнуляются и данные в карте. Как поступить в этом случае? Использовать массив из `ArrayList[]`? Не слишком ли это громоздко? Или использование `HashMap` в этом случае неоправданно и мне продолжать оперировать с моими изначальными массивами заголовков и данных? Но как-то вроде это не красиво.

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Parsing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName="http://trassagk.ru/trassa_azs/locator/";
        ArrayList<String> headers = contentToArray(fileName, "th");
        ArrayList<String> tableData = contentToArray(fileName, "td");
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> columns = divideTable(headers, tableData);

        for(int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(columns.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> contentToArray(String fileName, String contentType)
    {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(fileName).get();
            Elements element = doc.select(contentType);
            ArrayList<String> returnData = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element x : element)
            {
                if (x.hasText()) returnData.add(x.text());
                else if (x.children().hasText()) returnData.add(x.children().text());
                else if (x.children().hasAttr("alt")) returnData.add(x.children().attr("alt"));
                else returnData.add("");
            }
            return returnData;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> divideTable(ArrayList<String> head, ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int x = 0; x < head.size(); x++) {
            for (int y = x+1; y < data.size() ; y = y + head.size()) {
                buffer.add(data.get(y));
            }

            System.out.println(head.get(x));
            for (String s : buffer) System.out.println(s);

            map.put(head.get(x), buffer);
            buffer.clear();

        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените код добавления в `HashMap` на данный

```
map.put(head.get(x), new ArrayList<String>(buffer));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно не очищать буфер вовсе. Строчку `ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();` перенесите в внутрь первого цикла, а строчку `buffer.clear();` просто удалите.

Логика такая:
Для каждой строки из `head` создаём новый список и ссылку на этот список кладём в `buffer`. Заполняем список данными из `data` во втором цикле. Затем ссылку на этот список записываем в нашу карту. На следующей итерации в `buffer` будет записана новая ссылка на новый пустой список, а на старый список ссылка будет храниться только в HashMap.